# How to use pre-trained image classifier tensorflow model in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have create a image classifier with keras , and then save the model in  `.pb` format . The model is simple , it can only detect cat and dog .

I want to use that saved model in android .

This is what I have tried so far . I am using the following dependencies

`implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.13.1'`

Then I convert the image into byte array .

```
private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/tf_model.pb";

TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
inferenceInterface.feed("conv2d_4_input", readBytes(ims),  1,64,64);
inferenceInterface.fetch("output_node/Softmax",output);
inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"output_node/Softmax"});
```

But I get the following error.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer with 136886 elements is not compatible with a Tensor with shape [1, 64, 64]
```

Not sure, what can I do now . However , I can classify image in python , using following code .

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
```

Comment: There is a problem in the input shape of your image. Why don't you use TensorFlow Lite which makes inferencing much more easier?

Comment: You can see the file here for reference -> https://github.com/shubham0204/Skinly_for_Melanoma/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/health/inceptionapps/skinly/TFRecognizerClasses/SkinDiseaseRecognizer.java